# Recursion ocaml stack overflow

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml, stack-overflow

I'm trying to draw fractal: for every circle displeyed I want to draw circle half it's size to the left and right of that circle. Here is my code:

```
let rec drawCircle x y r =
    let halfSize = r/2 in
        draw_circle x y r;
        drawCircle (x+r) y halfSize;
        drawCircle (x-r) y halfSize;;
```

It compiles but when I run it I get stack overflow. The question is why and how can I fix it in this function ?

Comment: Just to clarify Bor Laze's answer if you don't see what's meant: Your function will keep calling itself over and over again until you get a stack overflow.  It calls itself (twice), and then those two invocations of the function call itself again (twice), and so on forever.  Or:  If you only want to draw two circles near every base level circle, it looks like you should replace the two instances of `drawCircle` in the body of the function, with `draw_circle`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't have any conditions to terminate recursion.

For example, do not call drawCircle again when r == 1 pixel. Or any other case on your choice.